# The system cannot find the file specified (randomly occurs)

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file in which I download files from an FTP server. Before hand it creates a folder based on the date/time. If there are no files to download the program delete the file. However it only deletes the files 90% (give or take) of the time. The other times it throws the error `The system cannot find the file specified`. I am not sure what makes the difference or why occasionally it doesn't work. If makes a difference the batch script is being run on a Windows Server 2012 R2.

```
ping ##.#.###.# -n 1 -w 1000
set FileName=%DATE:~10,4%-%DATE:~4,2%-%DATE:~7,2%_%TIME:~0,2%-%TIME:~3,2%

if %errorlevel% EQU 1 (
    :: Create timestamp of failed ping
    echo "Unable to ping. Timestamp: %FileName%" > "Archive-FileTransferProd\%FileName%.txt"
) else (

    :: Create folder on server based on current datetime (24 hour)
    md %FileName%

    :: FTP Commands
    :: Logg in to FTP
    echo user %UserName%> ftpCmd.dat
    echo %Password%>> ftpCmd.dat
    echo prompt>> ftpCmd.dat

    :: Copy items to server
    echo lcd "%FileName%">> ftpCmd.dat
    echo mget *>> ftpCmd.dat

    :: Delete files on server
    ::echo mdel *>> ftpCmd.dat

    :: Disconnect and clean up connection
    echo disconnect>> ftpCmd.dat
    echo bye>> ftpCmd.dat
    ftp -n -s:ftpcmd.dat %Server%
    del ftpCmd.dat


    set cnt=0
    for %%A in ("%FileName%\*") do set /a cnt+=1

    echo File name = %FileName%
    echo Count is = %cnt%

    :: If the folder is empty delete it
    IF %cnt% EQU 0 (
    echo File Deleted?
        rd /S /Q "C:\FileTransfer\%FileName%"
    ) 

)
```

**Additional Info**

I have been going through the command prompt and found the following. The code used doesn't assign the proper name to the folder. This happens whether the code is `md %FileName%` or `md "%FileName%"`

[image]

Comment: I see a left parentheses in your picture that is not in your code. Are you not showing us all the code?

Comment: Your new picture proves that my first comment was true. You are not showing us all the code and you are wrong thinking it was inconsequential. You are inside a code block.  When you post all your code I will tell you the newbie mistake you are making.

Comment: You even have output in your picture that you have no code for in your question.  You realize it would be alot easier to copy and paste the text output instead of posting a picture.

Comment: Updated, the picture was to show the output.

Comment: Between not using delayed expansion for variables and using `::` to comment inside of code blocks, I'm surprised the script works at all.

Comment: That code still does not match the output in your picture. You changed something in your code.

Comment: You should also take note of the message (about line 14 in your posted report) `"The system cannot find the drive specified"` which indicates that the `md` was not successful.

Answer (score 0):

Change
"%FileName%"\* to
"%FileName%\*"

Also Change
`rd /S /Q C:\FileTransfer\"%FileName%"`
to
`rd /S /Q "C:\FileTransfer\%FileName%"`